# How to print two columns in ascending order from 2 tables without common column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

this question was asked to me in interview i was not able give a answer i tried every solution internet did not gave desired output in oracle sql
input table table A has ID column and table B has Value columns
``table A`
ID(table A)     Value(table B)
1       E
2       C
3       B
4       A
5       D

```
output table wants
```

ID  Value

1       A
2       B
3       C
4       D
5       E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can both order your numbers table and the letters table and then join the numbers table with the letters table on the row number of the letter table:

```
SELECT numbers.id, letters.value FROM
(SELECT id
FROM tableA) numbers
JOIN 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY value) id, value
FROM tableB ) letters
ON numbers.id = letters.id
ORDER BY numbers.id, letters.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This simply seems a ROW_NUMBER window function -

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY value) id, value
  FROM your_table
 ORDER BY value;
```

Comment: hi ankit thanks for your solution. i forgot to mention the full question  that there are 2 different tables tableA has "key" column and tableB has "value" column from both table i want to print above desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can match the tables by using `ASCII()` function as ordering by one of the `id` or `value` columns while using a `CROSS JOIN` such as

```sql
SELECT id, value
  FROM tableA 
 CROSS JOIN tableB
 WHERE ASCII(value)-64 = id  
 ORDER BY id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=01edbde08e55e975ecc8281faf2655c1)</kbd>